# How to handle blank cells in a dataset

Tags: excel, pandas, excel-formula, data-cleaning

I am analyzing a large data set on the weather from Kaggle.com website.I need to handle blank cells in the data,clean it and then load into MySQL database .Seems like I should not be replacing blank values with 0 using excel sheet.I am not sure how to handle blank cells.what kind of scripts should I perform to handle a blank cell .Help needed please

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Excel has the capability to select and input formulas into blank cells inside of a range using the "Go To Special" button. If you were looking to put a formula into your blank cells or input a particular value into them that would be were I would recommend starting.

Id recommend looking this if that interests you and you're unfamiliar with that ability of excel.
https://www.contextures.com/xlDataEntry02.html